# How to prevent Internet Explorer from playing wav files?

Tags: internet-explorer, audio, settings, mime-types, wav

Unfortunately I've a problem with IE =( I have a service on IIS that returns me a wav file. So if I go to the URL of the service, IE tries to play returned wav file with Window Media Player.

Can I set any setting in the IE (7 or 8) to deny it play wav file with WMP and allow only show Open \ Save \ Cancel dialog?

Usually I use Firefox and it has parameters to set actions for different MIME type. Is there anything similar with IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried it, but does adding

```
Content-Disposition=attachment
```

to the response header fields help?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make IIS serve `wav` files with `application/octet-stream` mime type?

Answer (score 1):

If Kalmi's answer doesn't work and you're on IE8, you can also try adding this to the response header:

```
Response.AddHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
```

Not sure if that will kill IE's MIME handling all-together, but it's another thing to try.